# ConsumerWidget is not showing

Tags: flutter, dart

ConsumerWidget do not connected with extends so is not recoznize. i dont know solved . please help.

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';
import 'package:provider_learn/model/list_model.dart';
import 'package:provider_learn/widgets/list_item_widget.dart';
import 'package:provider_learn/widgets/title_widget.dart';
import 'package:provider_learn/widgets/toolbar.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ToDo extends ConsumerWidget {//first wrong is here 
  ToDo({super.key}); //second wrong is here 
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref)// and third wrons is here
 {
    return SafeArea( //  these codes are linked to in other windows in SafeArea's
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              TitleWidget(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "bugün yapılacaklar"),
                  onSubmitted: (value) => {},
                ),
              ),
              ToolBarWidget(),
              for (var i = 0;
                  i < toDoList.length;
                  i++) // dongüyle liste uzunluğu kadar madde oluşturduk
                Dismissible(
                  // dismissible widgetı ile sağa ve sola kaydırınca silinmesini sağladık.
                  key: ValueKey(toDoList[i]
                      .id), // listenin her maddesinin idsine göre ayarladık ona göre kaydırdığımızı siliyor
                  child: ListItemWidget(
                    item: toDoList[i],
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ConsumerWidget` is included in package `flutter_riverpod` and not included in `riverpod`.

So replace `import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';` with `import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';`